# Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 62 in /.../libraries/functions.php on line 316

Tags: php

Man oh man I cannot figure this out... Please help.
What a missing here?

here are the errors:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 62 in /..../libraries/functions.php on line 316
Notice: Undefined variable: stilldo in /..../libraries/functions.php on line 322
```

Here is the code:

```
function generate_password($length = 12, $letters = true, $mixed_case = true, $numbers = true, $punctuation = false){

    ## Generate the alfa
    $alfa = '';
    if($letters == true)    $alfa .= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if($mixed_case == true) $alfa .= strtoupper('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    if($numbers == true)    $alfa .= '0123456789';
    if($punctuation == true)$alfa .= '~!@#$%^&*(),.=+<>';

    ## Set Random Seed
    if(!function_exists('_generate_password_seed')):
    function _generate_password_seed(){
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
        return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
    }
    endif;
    srand(_generate_password_seed());

    ## Generate the password
    $token = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $token .= $alfa[@rand(0, @strlen($alfa))];
    }

    ## Check the length
    if(strlen($token) < $length){
        // echo $stilldo = $length - strlen($token);
        $token .= generate_password($stilldo);
    }

    ## Return the password
    return $token;
}
```

I get this error 5 out of 10 times i run this function and I can't seem to crack it.

Comment: Blah, the $stilldo error I know. :) it's the Uninitialized string error I'm struggling with.

Comment: Valid indices for `$alfa` are `0` through `strlen($alfa) - 1` inclusive. `strlen('a') == 1`...

Comment: OMG!!!!! seriously.... Clearly i've been up for too long. lol.. Thank you so much - I saw that but doubted my tired mind.

Answer (score 0):

`Notice: Undefined variable: stilldo` means, that a variable `$stilldo` is not defined, nor initialized... That means, that You call function `generate_password` in recursion when passing it an undefined variable, that in fact has a null value. Therefore Your function cannot work properly.

The part of your code should look like this:

```
## Check the length
if(strlen($token) < $length){
    $stilldo = $length - strlen($token);
    $token .= generate_password($stilldo);
}
```

Yes, a stupid mistake - You commented out the right line (where only `echo` should be commented out or deleted).

Enjoy!

Comment: sorry about that... i posted an edited version of the code, not the original.  Fixed that after i posted. ;) thanks though.